# Unsynonimyze cups and printing

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I can print without CUPS and I can ask a CUPS question without asking about printing. They are closely related tags but separated enough to be on their own. There are several CUPS related tags in the site, so why CUPS itself doesn't have its own?

- [Log files (CUPS) grow so fast!](https://askubuntu.com/q/237019/169736) <--- CUPS administration question, nothing to do with printing.
- [Library search paths](https://askubuntu.com/q/229060/169736) <--- CUPS backend question. Again, nobody is trying to print anything
- [Printing a file from server](https://askubuntu.com/q/108411/169736) <--- printing file from server, cups is a possible answer, but not the only one.
- [How to print file directly, circumventing the print dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/q/191210/169736) <--- printing from chromium and prevent the dialog, again, CUPS is not related
- [On typing dev/usb/lp0 it says 'no such file or directory'](https://askubuntu.com/q/235183/169736) <--- printing using lp, which can be used without CUPS
- [cups-lpd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cups-lpd)

Technical accuracy prevents confusion with the users and makes experts feel more welcomed.